# AttributeError: module 'grpc.experimental.aio' has no attribute 'Call' in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I was about to publish this as a bug on the Pub/Sub [repo](https://github.com/googleapis/python-pubsub/issues), but I thought I'd ask here first.

I'm just trying to set up an HTTP-triggered Cloud Function that will act as a Webhook and upon receiving a POST request will publish a message. It seems simple enough, so I coded it up and deployed it. However, it kept crashing. So I tried running it locally using functions-framework, and found the culprit to be `from google.cloud import pubsub_v1` which is causing the error `AttributeError: module 'grpc.experimental.aio' has no attribute 'Call'`

## Environment details

Running on a Cloud Function with Python 3.7

## Code example

#### main.py

```py
from flask import Flask, request, abort, Response
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64
import os
import requests

from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def connectToSheets(request):
    # Do stuff

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

#### requirements.txt

```
# Dependencies
flask==1.1.2
requests==2.24.0
google-cloud-pubsub==1.7.0
```

## Stack trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\functions-framework.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 764, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 717, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 956, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 555, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\functions_framework\_cli.py", line 37, in _cli
    app = create_app(target, source, signature_type)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\functions_framework\__init__.py", line 229, in create_app
    spec.loader.exec_module(source_module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Cookiestruct - Summer 2020 Internship\Automation\Artist\cloudpy\connectToShopify\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\pubsub_v1\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from google.cloud.pubsub_v1 import publisher
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\pubsub_v1\publisher\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from google.cloud.pubsub_v1.publisher.client import Client
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\pubsub_v1\publisher\client.py", line 32, in <module>
    from google.cloud.pubsub_v1.gapic import publisher_client
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\pubsub_v1\gapic\publisher_client.py", line 28, in <module>
    import google.api_core.gapic_v1.client_info
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\gapic_v1\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from google.api_core.gapic_v1 import method_async  # noqa: F401
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\gapic_v1\method_async.py", line 20, in <module>
    from google.api_core import general_helpers, grpc_helpers_async
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers_async.py", line 38, in <module>
    class _WrappedCall(aio.Call):
AttributeError: module 'grpc.experimental.aio' has no attribute 'Call'
```

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: Hi @SamiJunior I would recommend you to follow and the raise go on and raise a bug on Pub/Sub [repository](https://github.com/googleapis/python-pubsub/issues), as this seems to be a bug related to it, they will be able to better address it.